# I want to rename value of JSON File to readable Text with key/value in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, key-value

I have a data-table with some data, on a click at any row we get some detail information, the details come from JSON File and i want to rename the value with key value.  Because the data looks like "some_information" and i wanna show somenthing like "Some information"

I was thinking i could do it with map in child Component, or with ngSwitch Loop in child html file. But it's not working.

[Working Stuff here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vr9fqv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning the `dataSource`, you can do the following to modify the `name` value:

```
ELEMENT_DATA.forEach(el => {
  // first we replace any '_' with an empty space
  // then we capitalize each first letter of `name` words.
  let modifiedName = el.name.replace(/\_/g, ' ');
  modifiedName = modifiedName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + modifiedName.slice(1);
  el.name = modifiedName;
})
```